# C# Convert Decimal (String) to Regular String

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a string with encoded text using decimal, how would I decode the decimal in it using C#?

The string looks like:

```
"03211212122771217573772312402503648" - The original C# line compiled.

0 32 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 77 121 75 73 77 2 3 1 2 4 0 2 5 0 3 6 4 8 - The spaces between each ASCII character / decimal set.
```

All of the spaces in between are spaces between ASCII characters.

Thanks.

Edit:

I guess my question wasn't clear...

It's currently in a number format in a string, encoded as char.

I want to decode the data in it to send to the server.

The server does not accept numbers, but instead, wants raw data, how would I go about doing this? Like: 77 - M 121 - y etc...

How would I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "new decimal characters"? How are you meant to know where the gaps between characters are?

Comment: Could you elaborate? For example, is the first line the source, the second the desired output? If so, how are we to determine that 77, 121, 75, etc. shouldn't be 7 7 1 2 1 7 5...?

Comment: How is the text encoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. By concatenating the values without a separator, you have omitted information that is needed to decode the string.

If we examine the string from the start, you don't get far before it's impossible to determine what it means.

The first value could be determined to be `0`, if you know that no values are stored with leading zeroes, e.g. `032`.

A the second value it's no longer possible to determine what the original was. It could have been `3`, `32`, `321`, or even `321121212277121757377`.

#### Edit:

If you add a separator between the numbers, it's easy to parse the string:

```
int[] values = str.Split('-').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
```

Explanation of the code:

`str.Split('-')` returns an array of strings, where each string contains a number.

`.Select(Int32.Parse)` will parse each string into a number, it's a shorter form of `.Select(s => Int32.Parse(s))`. The lambda expression is not needed as the `Int32.Parse` method already fits to create a delegate for the `Select` method.

`.ToArray()` converts the `IEnumerable<int>` that `Select` returns into an array of integers.

Comment: If I add a "-" or " " between each set would that make it possible? And if so, how would I parse it then?

Comment: @Eric: Yes, then it's easy to parse the string: `int[] values = str.Split('-').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();`

Comment: I guess my question wasn't clear...

It's currently in a number format in a string, encoded as char. I want to decode the data in it to send to the server. The server does not accept numbers, but instead, wants raw data, how would I go about doing this?

Like: 77 - M
121 - y

etc... How would I do this?

Comment: You mean that you want to convert each number into the character with that character code? Use `.Select(s => (char)Int32.Parse(s))` in the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

If you put spaces between the different numbers, you could have something like:

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = "1 2 3 4 5".Split().Select(s => int.Parse(s));
```